# FOP/ikvm: error "Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl not found"

Tags: apache-fop, ikvm

I have produced a fop.dll from fop-1.0 with ikvm:

```
ikvmc -target:library -reference:IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll -recurse:{myPathToJars}\*.jar -version:1.0 -out:{myPathToJars}\fop.dll
```

If I use my fop.dll in a Windows Application, everything works perfect.
If I use it in a Class Library, I get the following error:

```
"Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl not found" at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance()
```

The code line is:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

Here is the code of method:

```
        public static void xmlToPDF(String xmlPath, String xslPath, SortedList arguments, String destPdfPath)
        {
            java.io.File xmlfile = new java.io.File(xmlPath);
            java.io.File pdffile = new java.io.File(destPdfPath);
            try
            {
                // configure fopFactory as desired
                FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

                FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
                // configure foUserAgent as desired

                // Setup output
                OutputStream outputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
                outputStream = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

                try
                {
                    // Construct fop with desired output format
                    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf" /*MimeConstants.MIME_PDF*/, foUserAgent, outputStream);

                    // Setup XSLT
                    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                    java.io.File xsltfile = new java.io.File(xslPath);
                    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile.getAbsoluteFile()));

                    // Set the value of a  in the stylesheet
                    if (arguments != null)
                    {
                        IList keys = arguments.GetKeyList();
                        foreach (var key in keys)
                        {
                            Object value = arguments[key];
                            transformer.setParameter(key.ToString(), value);
                        }

                    }

                    // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                    Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                    // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                    // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                    transformer.transform(src, res);
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    outputStream.close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I used ikvm-0.46.0.1 to make my fop.dll (based on fop 1.0). I included the following jars:

```
avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
batik-all-1.7.jar
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
fop.jar
serializer-2.7.0.jar
xalan-2.7.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar
```

Any idea why this error occurs? Why is the behaviour different between Windows Application and Class Library?

**Addition 10/19/11:**
I managed to get working the following:

- MyMainPrg (a Windows Forms Application)
- MyFopWrapper (a Class Library that calls fop.dll)

But for my case this is not the solution, because in my target project, I have the following structure:

- MainCmdLinePrg  (a Console Application; calls DLL_1)
- DLL_1     (calls DLLsharedFop)  {there are several DLLs that can call DLLsharedFop}
- DLLsharedFop   (calls directly fop.dll; or - I don't care - might call MyFopWrapper)

Unfortunately this construct results in the error.
You can shorten to a pair (ACmdLinePrg,MyFopWrapper): already this does not work! But (MyMainPrg,MyFopWrapper) does...

Comment: The problem's going to be `com.sun.org.apache` - that should just be `org.apache`. No idea where it's getting the extra bit from, though.

Comment: If I look in IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Transform.dll then I clearly see the com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl class right there, yet I have the same problem.  Yes the Transform dll is referenced and in the same directory.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I got that error and how I resolved:

My solultion looks like this:

```
ClientApp (references)--> ClassLibrary1
```

My ClassLibrary1 public functions are using, but *not exposing* any IKVM related objects, therefore the caller (ClientApp) did not have to add IKVM references. All is good in compile time.

However in runtime, the situation is different. I got the same exception and realized that ClientApp also needed to reference the correct IKVM dll (**IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Transform.dll**) that contains "**com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax**" namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved a similar problem by adding the following before the problematic line:

```
var s = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl();
var t = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

[As described here](https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/issues/21)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dll with the missing class in your working directory?

If you have the dll then it is a classloader problem. Look in the [IKVM wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader). Often the BootClassPathAssemby help.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not find "ikvm.runtime.Startup. ..." in my IKVM.Runtime , though it's V0.46.0.1. How can implement/include this? My IDE isn't at all happy with a line "ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssemby(Assembly.Load("MyLovelyDll"));".

Comment: Hmm.. the part "Startup" is seen as internal. I downloaded the sources and looking at "openjdk.cs", where you have the "IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime" namespace, you see:
namespace IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime
{
 static class Startup
 {

So the reaction on internal is, I think, normal. Shouldn't it be declared like: namespace IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime
{
 public static class Startup
 {
 
as in the other classes above?

Comment: The class is in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **NuGet** Packages of **FOP.dll v1.1.0** and **IKVM** pacakges of v7.1.45 in C#.NET app. I got this issue on Windows 2016 x64 server with error messages like:

> ------------------------------ Fop.cs (111): Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
>   not found -    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance()
>   Fop.cs (125): Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
>   -    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance()\r\n   at org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder..ctor(Boolean
>   enableNamespaces)\r\n   at
>
> ### org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder..ctor()\r\n

I resolved the problem by adding those two lines at begins of procedure

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl s = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl();
            com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl t = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

helpful link:

> https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

> "Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl not found"

means more or less that the type cannot be found, which means that a dll is missing.

in this case the **IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Transform.dll**, where the type `TransformerFactoryImpl` is defined.

or any other of the `IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.*.dll`

- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Parse.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Transform.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.XPath.dll